# AS3 : yet another 1009 error: where's that null object

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, starling-framework

I've got 1009 error, but I can't find that *null object*. Can someone point it out to me?

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a
>   property or method of a null object reference.
>
> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a
>   property or method
>   of a null object reference. at
>   Square/draw()[/Users/si/Dropbox/ac3/square/src/Square.as:21] at
>   Start/drawSquare()[/Users/si/Dropbox/ac3/square/src/Start.as:35] at
>   starling.events::EventDispatcher/invokeEvent()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:146]
>   at
>   starling.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as:117]
>   at
>   starling.display::DisplayObject/dispatchEvent()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/display/DisplayObject.as:398]
>   at
>   starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEvent()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/display/DisplayObjectContainer.as:379]
>   at
>   starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEventWith()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/display/DisplayObjectContainer.as:389]
>   at
>   starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/display/DisplayObjectContainer.as:135]
>   at
>   starling.core::Starling/initializeRoot()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/core/Starling.as:439]
>   at
>   starling.core::Starling/initialize()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/core/Starling.as:410]
>   at
>   starling.core::Starling/onContextCreated()[/Users/redge/Dropbox/Development/starling/starling/src/starling/core/Starling.as:649]

It's starling project it it matters.

Here's the code:

```
package {
   import starling.display.*;
   import com.greensock.TweenLite;
   import com.greensock.easing.Linear;

public class Square extends Sprite implements ISquare {

    public const square:Quad = new Quad(100, 100);
    private var direction:Boolean;
    private var stopped:Boolean;
    private var speed:int;

    public function Square() {
    }

    public function draw():void{
        addChild(square);
        square.color = 0x4500FF;
        direction = new Boolean(true);
        stopped = new Boolean(false);
        speed = new int(stage.stageHeight);
        trace("vars init complete");
        down();
    }

   ...
```

Here's the whole soure on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9x2q93o2ff1fsna/AADVJgt5nipDE1pdkgozkOc1a

Comment: Please post the entire error that you get.

Comment: There! I've edited it in the question. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: If you want to get more error information I recommend using a debug flash player (if that works with starling? It's just flash, right?)

Comment: I use flash player debug and yes its just flash. (pure AS3) I just copied this part. Thanks for the answer. Now I have to go through my code to confirm it. :)

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're not getting filenames and linenumbers. Maybe try testing with a debug build instead of a release build.

Comment: sorry I didn't copy the whole error code. I thought this was enough. I'll edit it again.

Comment: Those this now tells you anything more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57673/discussion-between-pimgd-and-ozr3n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, let's take a look at the relevant code...

Start class

```
//stuff omitted like imports
public class Start extends Sprite {

    public var viewport:Quad = new Quad(1,1);
    private var swipe:SwipeGesture;
    private var call:Square = new Square();

    public function Start() {
        super();

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, drawSquare);
    }

    private function drawSquare(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, drawSquare);

        viewport.width = stage.stageWidth;
        viewport.height = stage.stageHeight;
        viewport.color = 0x414141;
        addChild(viewport);

        swipe = new SwipeGesture(viewport);
        swipe.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_RECOGNIZED, onSwipe);

        trace("gesture listener added");
        call.draw();
    }
    //stuff omitted
}
```

Square class

```
//imports omitted
public class Square extends Sprite implements ISquare {

    public const square:Quad = new Quad(100, 100);
    private var direction:Boolean;
    private var stopped:Boolean;
    private var speed:int;

    public function Square() {
    }

    public function draw():void{
        addChild(square);
        square.color = 0x4500FF;
        direction = new Boolean(true);
        stopped = new Boolean(false);
        speed = new int(stage.stageHeight);
        trace("vars init complete");
        down();
    }
    //stuff omitted
}
```

When I manually read your code, I see that this is what happens:

- Start.constructor adds eventlistener
- eventListener triggers, `start.drawSquare`
- adds viewport, does stuff with swipegesture...
- draws square
- Square.draw is called
- Square adds a quad to itself
- sets some colors and variables
- direction to true
- stopped to false
- speed to `stage.stageHeight`

Wait, `stage`? `stage` has not been mentioned around `Square` yet. I think it's null. And in fact, when you look at the stack trace of the error, you can see this. It says it goes wrong at `at Square/draw() in /Users/si/Dropbox/ac3/square/src/Square.as:21`. And line 21 of Square.as is `speed = new int(stage.stageHeight);` This shows that one of the mentioned objects on that line is null or otherwise undefined. Via a process of elimination, we can see that `speed` has already been declared, and is being assigned to and is thus irrelevant; the int class is defined or the compiling would have gone wrong; and all we are left with is either `stage` being null or `stage.stageHeight` being undefined.

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight) says `Stage.stageHeight` is an int. It's a property of stage, and since it's a primitive type, it's never null or otherwise undefined (not in actionscript, anyway). So that leaves us with `stage`: the `call` instance of Start has never been added to `stage`, thus stage is null, thus it nulls on

`speed = new int(stage.stageHeight)`

To fix this, either pass the draw function of Square a reference to `stage`... or, and this seems to be the better solution, given what you want to do, **add call (that's the Square instance) to stage before drawing it.**

Comment: How is possible that _stage.stageHeight_ is null if I can trace it in the Start.as at the begining of execution??

Comment: Because it's null in `Square.as`. And square isn't added to start on the display list, it's just a property/attribute.

Comment: You should propose a fix, such as using `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener in your answer.

Comment: @Vesper I did propose a fix (before you made your comment). You say to use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`, but when I look through OP's code, I don't see the Square instance `call` being added to stage anywhere at all. So that would just cause the Square instance not to be rendered at all.